# Eclipse CDT Kepler Importing Makefile project

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, include

I would love to import a Makefile project from Eclipse, and have all the different includes path that the compiler uses to create correctly my Eclipse project.

Unfortunately, those path, specified on the command line by a "-I" don't show up in Project Explorer and I have to add them by hand.

I am currently importing the project using the standard "Import project from Makefile" built in Eclipse.

If I'm not wrong there was an autodiscovery option in older versions of Eclipse, but it's not there anymore.

How do you do for having all your include paths set up without too much hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is **NOT** to use

`File->New->Makefile Project with Existing Code`

but to use

`File->New->C++ Project`

and then to select

`Makefile project->Empty project`.

After you set up such a dummy project, you simply copy your existing source to that project directory, hit F5 (i.e. Refresh) and change the build command to use your `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using Luna.  I imported using File->New->C++->Makefile Project with Existing Code.

Prior to launching eclipse, you have to be sure to source any files that set required environment variables.

I did have some build options which were not the standard all and clean, so I had to add those configurations individually.

1. source files to setup your environment.
2. Launch Eclipse
3. Import C++ Makefile project
4. Setup Build options.
5. Click the hammer.